# SYNC FRAMEWORK-Batching

Tags: wcf, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, batching

I am able to synchronize two remote databases using sync framework 2.1 over WCF(N-Tier) .

To improve performance while transferring large data, I implemented Batching.

But I am facing below error message:

```
An unexpected error occurred when applying batch file 1e1855e6-0b9a-4332-9fdb-07a25bc1bd49.batch. See the inner exception for more details.
```

This is happening only with last batch file. When applying last batch file in the set of batch files the code is terminating with above error message.

Below I am pasting xml format of webservice log (inner exception):

```
<InnerException>
<ExceptionType>System.IO.FileNotFoundException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,     Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
<Message>Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\1e1855e6-0b9a-4332-9fdb-07a25bc1bd49.batch'.</Message>
<StackTrace>
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchInfoFactory.Deserialize(String batchFileName, Boolean deserializeData)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchConsumer.ReadBatchFile(UInt32 lookupLocation, UInt32 expectedNumber)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchConsumer.ReadBatchFile(UInt32 expectedNumber, String&amp; batchFileName)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchConsumer.ApplyBatches(DbSyncScopeMetadata scopeMetadata, DbSyncSession syncSession, SyncSessionStatistics sessionStatistics)
</StackTrace>
<ExceptionString>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\1e1855e6-0b9a-4332-9fdb-07a25bc1bd49.batch'.
File name: 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\1e1855e6-0b9a-4332-9fdb-07a25bc1bd49.batch'
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchInfoFactory.Deserialize(String batchFileName, Boolean deserializeData)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchConsumer.ReadBatchFile(UInt32 lookupLocation, UInt32 expectedNumber)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchConsumer.ReadBatchFile(UInt32 expectedNumber, String&amp; batchFileName)
at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbSyncBatchConsumer.ApplyBatches(DbSyncScopeMetadata scopeMetadata, DbSyncSession syncSession, SyncSessionStatistics sessionStatistics)         
</ExceptionString>
</InnerException>
```

Your help and suggestions are very much appreciated!!

Thank you in advance friends!!

Answer (score 0):

try moving out your batching directory outside of IIS folder.

Comment: batchingdirectory is set to %temp% folder on both source and destination providers. The inner exception(pasted above) is saying   :"Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\1e1855e6-0b9a-4332-9fdb-07a25bc1bd49.batch'" .plz help me why inetsrv couldnot pick the file...uploadbatchfile methods is uploading all batchfiles successfully, but dont know why code is terminatiing.